# Better Method for Multiple Meta Boxes

Tags: custom-field, customization, metabox

I'm learning about meta boxes and have gotten them to appear on my local dev, but I can't figure out how to avoid creating new functions for saving multiple meta boxes.

I assume that I could call an array and reuse the same functions for generating the meta box content and saving it, but I keep getting errors when trying so. Here is the code I have now in my functions file:

```
    /**
     * Home Page Custom Meta Content
     *
    **/

    // Add the Meta Box  
    function add_home_meta_box() {  
        add_meta_box(  
            'home_meta_box', // $id  
            'Home Page Content', // $title   
            'show_home_meta_box', // $callback  
            'page', // $page  
            'normal', // $context  
            'high'); // $priority
        add_meta_box(  
            'home_meta_box_lower_1', // $id  
            'Home Lower Left', // $title   
            'show_home_meta_box_lower_left', // $callback  
            'page', // $page  
            'normal', // $context  
            'high'); // $priority    
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_home_meta_box');  


    // Creating Array for Fields
    $prefix = 'home_';
    $home_meta_fields = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H2 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Caption Sub Title',
            'desc' => 'Upper section H3 caption title.',
            'id' => $prefix.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Caption',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(  
            'name'  => 'Caption Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 1140px wide x 530px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        )
    );// end caption array

    $prefix2 = 'home_lower_left';
    $home_meta_fields_lower_left = array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Title',
            'desc' => 'H2 title for column.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(  
            'name'  => 'Column Image',  
            'desc'  => 'Upload a pre-cropped 360px wide x 300px tall web-optimized image.',  
            'id'    => $prefix2.'image',  
            'type'  => 'image'  
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Column Sub-Title',
            'desc' => 'H3 sub-title above text block.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'sub_title',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
      array(  
          'label'=> 'Text block',  
          'desc'  => 'Caption text block.',  
          'id'    => $prefix2.'caption',  
          'type'  => 'textarea'  
      ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button Label',
            'desc' => 'Button link label (what user reads on button).',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_label',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Button URL',
            'desc' => 'URL where button links to. Enter http:// to work.',
            'id' => $prefix2.'btn_url',
            'type' => 'text'
        )
    );// end lower left array


    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box() {
    global $home_meta_fields, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields;  

        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta');
    // Lower Left
    //The Callback
    function show_home_meta_box_lower_left() {
    global $home_meta_fields_lower_left, $post;
    // Using nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="home_meta_box_left_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

        //Begin field table and loop
        echo '<table class="form-table">';
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_left as $field) {
            // get value of this field if it exists for this page
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
            // begin a table row with
            echo '<tr>
                            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
                            <td>';
                            switch($field['type']) {
                                // case items will go here
                                // text  
                                case 'text':  
                                    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                // textarea  
                                case 'textarea':  
                                    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
                                        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
                                break;
                                case 'image':  
                                    $image = get_template_directory_uri().'library/images/img-preview-blank.png';    
                                    echo '<span class="custom_default_image" style="display:none">'.$image.'</span>';  
                                    if ($meta) { $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($meta, 'medium'); $image = $image[0]; }                 
                                    echo    '<input name="'.$field['id'].'" type="hidden" class="custom_upload_image" value="'.$meta.'" /> 
                                                <img src="'.$image.'" class="custom_preview_image" style="max-width:300px" alt="" /><br /> 
                                                    <input class="custom_upload_image_button button" type="button" value="Choose Image" /> 
                                                    <small> <a href="#" class="custom_clear_image_button">Remove Image</a></small> 
                                                    <br clear="all" /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'';  
                                break;  
                            } // end switch
            echo '</td></tr>';
        } // end foreach
        echo '</table>'; // end table
    }

    // Save the Data
    function save_home_meta_lower_left($post_id) {  
        global $home_meta_fields_lower_left;  

        // verify nonce  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_left_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
            return $post_id;  
        // check autosave  
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
            return $post_id;  
        // check permissions  
        if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
            if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
                return $post_id;  
            } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
                return $post_id;  
        }  

        // loop through fields and save the data  
        foreach ($home_meta_fields_lower_left as $field) {  
            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
            $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
            if ($new && $new != $old) {  
                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
            } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
            }  
        } // end foreach  
    }  
    add_action('save_post', 'save_home_meta_lower_left');
```

Thanks for helping me out! Much appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Edit your question to include the complete text of the messages.

Comment: Hey @s_ha_dum, I get a 500 error trying to wrap the [pre]$home_meta_fields[/pre] and [pre]$home_meta_fields_lower_left[/pre] arrays together.

Comment: Trying to wrap the arrays together? What does that mean?

Comment: Meta Box plugin's demo.php has a good example of bundling arrays for [multiple meta boxes](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/register-multiple-meta-boxes/), but I'm not where to start with his approach and what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sort of done this with using the same function to save the meta on the post screen and also on the quickedit. In your case I think you need to add an `or` clause to your nonce validation.

```
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))   
        return;
```

as

```
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_meta_box_left_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)) )   
       return;
```

Then you could check if the appropriate meta is posted and update for each box.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking for the info... Does the nonce check have to be used for each meta box individually?

Comment: I guess every metabox should have a nonce?  I get a little confused there and have definitely used the same nonce on both the posts page and on the quickedit exactly to get around this point.  I think WP even had its own default nonce for posts saving.

Comment: [looks like you need one for each box](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49453/do-i-need-a-nonce-field-for-every-meta-box-i-add-to-my-custom-post-type-admin)